# pointer behaviour inside function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I don't understand how does a function changes the state of the pointer when passed as a parameter. For example, in this code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inc(int* a) {
    a++;
}

void change(int* a) {
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 3;
}

int main() {

    int* a = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;

    printf("%d \n",*a);
    inc(a);
    printf("%d \n",*a);

    change(a);
    return 0;
}
```

It is observed that the pointer doesn't increment when I try to do using the function `inc()`.
But at the same time, `change()` does actually change the values of the pointer.

Can you explain why does `inc()` doesn't work?

Comment: everything in `c` is pass by value. For both functions, local copies of `a` are made. In `inc`, you simply increment that local copy and the changes are lost when you leave. In `change`, you dereference the local copy of the `a` pointer with the brackets, and so the changes made to that dereference persist outside of the function.

Comment: *"change() does actually change the values of the pointer"* - It chages the **pointed to** object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inc` *does* change the value of the pointer which is passed to it - but what's passed to it is a copy of the original pointer value, so the original remains unchanged.

`change` doesn't change the pointer itself, it changes what's being pointed at by the pointer.

If you want `inc` to change the original pointer you'll have to either change it to be a function which returns the incremented pointer, which you'd then assign to the original pointer:

```
int* inc(int* ip) {
  return ++ip;
}
```

and then in `main`:

```
a = inc(a);
```

Or you could rewrite `inc` to take a pointer-to-pointer as a parameter and then pass the address of the original pointer to it, as in:

```
void inc(int** ipp) {
  *ipp = *ipp + 1;
}
```

and then call it from `main` as:

```
inc(&a);
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great spot to draw some pictures. When you write

```
int* a = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

you get a setup that looks like this:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |  ?????  |  ?????  |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a
  in main
```

After assigning values to `a[0]` and `a[1]`, things look like this:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    1    |    2    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a
  in main
```

Now, let's suppose you call `inc(a)`. This passes a copy of the pointer `a` into the `inc` function. Since the *pointer* is the only thing that's copied, things now look like this:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    1    |    2    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a            ^
  in main             |
                      |
+---------+           |
| addr X  |-----------+
+---------+
 pointer a
   in inc
```

Notice that there are now two pointers named `a`, but they're not the same pointer. It's like if you have two friends named Zoe - they have the same name, but they're not the same person.

Inside `inc`, you wrote

```
a++;
```

which means "advance the pointer `a` to point to the next `int` after the one it's currently pointing at." This looks like this:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    1    |    2    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a                      ^
  in main                       |
                                |
+---------+                     |
| addr Y  |---------------------+
+---------+
 pointer a
   in inc
```

And notice that the `a` back in `main` is unchanged, since we're manipulating a copy of `a`. Again, think back to the Zoe analogy - if you talk to one person named Zoe, it doesn't mean you talked to the other person named Zoe. As a result, when `inc` returns, the copy of `a` vanishes into the aether, and we're left with this:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    1    |    2    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a
  in main
```

Since pointer is unchanged, which is why you see the same values before and after calling `inc`.

But calling `change` works differently. When you initially call `change`, things look like this:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    1    |    2    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a            ^
  in main             |
                      |
+---------+           |
| addr X  |-----------+
+---------+
 pointer a
 in change
```

When you now write

```
a[0] = 2;
```

you're saying "follow the pointer named `a`, see where you end up, and put the value `2` there. That means that we see the following:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    2    |    2    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a            ^
  in main             |
                      |
+---------+           |
| addr X  |-----------+
+---------+
 pointer a
 in change
```

Writing `a[1] = 3` also means "follow the pointer named `a`, go to the element at index `1` in what you find, and replace it with `3`. This gives the following:

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    2    |    3    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a            ^
  in main             |
                      |
+---------+           |
| addr X  |-----------+
+---------+
 pointer a
 in change
```

Now, after `change` returns, we're back in `main`. The `a` pointer in `main` hasn't changed - it's still looking in the same place as before - but the array that it's pointing at has had its values changed.

```
+---------+      +---------+---------+
| addr X  | ---> |    2    |    3    |
+---------+      +---------+---------+
 pointer a            
  in main
```

To summarize:

- Pointers are passed around in C by value, meaning that if you pass a pointer into a function, you're passing around a copy of the pointer.
- As a result, if a function that takes a pointer as an argument changes *where the pointer is pointing*, that will have no effect back in the calling function.
- However, if a function changes *the contents of what's being pointed at*, that will reflect in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
void inc(int* a) {
    a++;
```

Here `a` is passed by value and so changing `a` inside `inc()` will not be reflected outside.

```
void change(int* a) {
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 3;
```

Here also `a` is passed by value but you can use `a` to change what `a` is pointing to which is exactly what `a[0]` and `a[1]` do.

Answer (score 0):

`a++` increases the value of the local variable `a`. That is, stepping to next place in memory. If you want to increase it you should use `(*a)++`

The notation `a[1]` is just syntactic sugar to hide pointer arithmetics. What this really means is *(a+1). This has a funny side effect. `a[1]` is the same thing as `1[a]`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the `inc` function, it is changing the *value* of the parameter `a`.  Since all function parameters in C are pass by value, this change isn't reflected in the calling function.

When `change` is called, it does this:

```
a[0] = 2;
a[1] = 3;
```

Which is the same as this:

```
*(a + 0) = 2;
*(a + 1) = 3;
```

Specifically, the pointer `a` is being *dereferenced*.  The function is not changing `a`, but what `a` points to.  That's why the change is visible outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The code in `inc`

```
void inc(int* a) {
    a++;
}
```

changes the copy of the pointer value, and doesn't affect the parameter passed. To affect the parameter pass it by reference rather than value:

```
void inc(int*& a) {
    a++;
}
```